# Animated Progress Bars in QTableView - how?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtableview

I have a QTableView in which I want to draw a column with progress bars.
I considered the Qt Torrent example application and re-implemented the paint() function of the QStyledItemDelegate like this:

```
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    if index.column() == 1:

        progressBar = QtGui.QStyleOptionProgressBarV2()
        progressBar.state = QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled
        progressBar.direction = QtGui.QApplication.layoutDirection()
        progressBar.rect = option.rect
        progressBar.fontMetrics = QtGui.QApplication.fontMetrics()
        progressBar.minimum = 0
        progressBar.maximum = 100
        progressBar.textAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        progressBar.textVisible = True

        progressBar.progress = 20 # for testing

        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, progressBar, painter)

    return super(progressBarDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
```

However, this gave me a column of greyed-out progress bars - with no animation.  [Screenshot here.](http://www.bonhardapple.com/shared-with-others/delegated-style.png)
This isn't what the screenshots in the docs portray of the example.

Then I found out about QTableView's setIndexWidget().
I tried to implement setIndexWidget() whenever data() was called on the model but no progress bars were shown.
So I thought I'd try setIndexWidget() in the delegate paint() code.
I created a dictionary (self.parent.progressBarPool) to track which progress bars had been manufactured - to avoid excessive creation/deletion I guess.

```
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    if index.column() == 1:

        if not index.row() in self.parent.progressBarPool:
            progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar()
            self.parent.progressBarPool[index.row()] = progressBar
            progressBar.setMinimum(0)
            # progressBar.setAutoFillBackground(True) # docs say this needs to be true, but you get a better row-highlight appearance with it False
            self.parent.tableView.setIndexWidget(index, progressBar)
        else:
            progressBar = self.parent.progressBarPool[index.row()]

        progressBar.setValue(20) # for testing

    return super(progressBarDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
```

This looked great ([screenshot here](http://www.bonhardapple.com/shared-with-others/first-glance.png)), however, when I scrolled, the progress bars didn't move in concert with the rest of the scroll area.
They floated above the cells which scrolled away underneath them ([screenshot](http://www.bonhardapple.com/shared-with-others/scrolled.png))

I've now hacked things a bit so that the self.parent.progressBarPool is deleted when there's a wheelEvent.
This causes a flickery redraw on (one type of) scroll but feels like a growing stack of hacks rather than a solution.
Accordingly, I would appreciate any advice on the right way to do this.

With thanks,

Dave.

pyqt 4.10.1
qt 4.8.4
Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: Regarding the example, are you sending any `update()`s to the window so that it can be redrawn ? Or how about getting the QApplication to `processEvents()` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  In this example I don't have any 'updates' that I want to send: I just want to see the progress bars sitting, animated, at 20%.  There is nothing particularly _blocking_ the QApplication from processing events is there?

Comment: If your program is using all the CPU then you have to give up some time for the GUI to get updated. The main GUI event handler doesn't necessarily check and redraw everything just because your program is not blocking. I take it you are actually changing the progress value as your program runs? See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents for more details.